# possible to INclude duplicate rows?

Tags: mariadb, query, duplication

I have MariaDB version 10.2.14-MariaDB. I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `card_data_link` (
    `card_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `data_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    INDEX `card_id` (`card_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `data_id` (`data_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

It has this data:

```
card_id data_id
"63"    "21"
"34"    "3"
"34"    "21"
"34"    "21"
```

It joins to this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `card_data` (
    `data_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data` TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`data_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=51
;
```

It has data that looks like this:

```
data_id data
"21"    "{R}"
"3"     "{3}"
```

If I run this query:

```
select 
    cdl.card_id,
    cdl.data_id,
    cd.data
from
    card_data_link cdl
left join
    card_data cd on cd.data_id = cdl.data_id
group by
    cdl.card_id
    ,cd.data_id
```

results:

```
card_id    data_id    data
"34"        "3"     "{3}"
"34"        "21"    "{R}"
"63"        "21"    "{R}"
```

Is there a way I can get the second

```
"34"        "21"    "{R}"
```

row to show up so it returns:

```
card_id    data_id    data
"34"        "3"     "{3}"
"34"        "21"    "{R}"
"34"        "21"    "{R}"
"63"        "21"    "{R}"
```

It's like it's doing a select distinct, even though I'm not putting in distinct. Am I not grouping correctly? Thanks!

Comment: if you want duplicates, don't use `group by`

Comment: That worked, thank you, sir!

Comment: The only way this query would make any sense is to have a `COUNT` (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e3bd7a3c0865226fe1297cca788c6cc7)) with your `GROUP BY` - how do you distinguish between dupes? You also need a `FOREIGN KEY` declaration (`CONSTRAINT cdl_cd_fk FOREIGN KEY (data_id) REFERENCES card_data (data_id)` - see fiddle). In future could you please supply your data as DML and not just plain text - ideally in a fiddle (but be sure and post the DML here also).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP BY` aggregates the result values of the `SELECT` statement based on its arguments.

Removing the `GROUP BY` clause and arguments from your SQL will allow duplicates to be presented.

For MariaDB recommend `sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` (not default, [ref: manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#only_full_group_by)) to ensure that SQL statements are correctly formed with respect to `GROUP BY`.